# Document about relationship b/w GUI components

Tags: qt, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a little more in detail documentation about ROS GUI components?

I see at least 2 ROS stacks for GUI development, `qt_gui_core` and `rqt`. Both of which seem to contain some common packages but the hierarchy and their usage is unclear to me.

Because of that, I've drawn a simple [dependency diagram for GUI related components in ROS](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/14E3KYbszb-IfZIF5rvSrNpA9PO_UmGjHEKkM0mPxx5Y/edit) (focusing on python for now), expecting that clarifying hierarchy per each plugin would explain the difference of the common packages. However there I see some packages are depending on multiple of those common packages so that the role of each commong pkg remains unknown to me.

So before I start looking into source codes of those packages I just wanted to know if there's already good clarification somewhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43374/document-about-relationship-b/w-gui-components/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I conclude by myself that there's not much dependency b/w core components that the developers need to care; as far as we follow what's instructed on `rqt`'s tutorial, we use the proper dependency.

One thing I note currently is that `rqt_py_common` which is currently in [rqt_common_plugins](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_common_plugins) pkg provides common classes instead of plugins ([moving to common pkg is requested](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/13)).

Lastly, [API review](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/Reviews/2012-06-20_API_Review) compensates design decision to the great level.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recall seeing this note on the ROS-users mailing list:

https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20120802.065041.e5480542.en.html

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-09-08**:
+1 it's good to know that there was an announcement that describes the relationship b/w 2 `stack`s. I'll still wait for the ones about `package`s in those 2 `stack`s.